# Is it possibile to put two transmission servers in a cluster?

Tags: wireless, lan, transmission, cluster

I have two servers in two different lan's. The servers are connect with openVpn.

Is it possible have the servers operate as a cluster with 1 server as master and 1 server as slave? They would both work together to download the same torrent.

Comment: One thing to consider: this is useless if the vpn is connected over the same network and interface as the internet. Downloading in a cluster is only useful if the bottleneck is the individual server's internet connection. Downloading in a cluster would mean that the slave has to copy all it's downloaded bytes to the master over the VPN. If this VPN is over the internet, then both servers bandwith gets halved. The master now has to download from the internet and from the slave. The slave now has to download from the internet and upload to the master.